# Subsetting my data is not yielding the expected results

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 93 observations. There are only two variables, a factor (size, a number) and it's response (percent, also a number). The factor value ranges from 0-2000. I would like to combine these 93 observations into three groups based on factor values (0-2, 2-50, and 50-2000) and see the total combined response value for each.

Here is my data:

```
> data2
   run  size percentage
1    1 0.375      0.010
2    2 0.412      0.020
3    3 0.452      0.032
4    4 0.496      0.043
5    5 0.545      0.053
6    6 0.598      0.060
7    7 0.656      0.066
8    8 0.721      0.070
9    9 0.791      0.071
10  10 0.868      0.072
11  11 0.953      0.070
12  12 1.047      0.069
13  13 1.149      0.067
14  14 1.261      0.065
15  15 1.385      0.065
16  16 1.520      0.066
17  17 1.668      0.068
18  18 1.832      0.072
19  19 2.011      0.077
20  20 2.207      0.083
21  21 2.423      0.090
22  22 2.660      0.097
23  23 2.920       0.10
24  24 3.205       0.11
25  25 3.519       0.12
26  26 3.863       0.13
27  27 4.240       0.13
28  28 4.655       0.14
29  29 5.110       0.14
30  30 5.610       0.14
31  31 6.158       0.14
32  32 6.760       0.14
33  33 7.421       0.15
34  34 8.147       0.15
35  35 8.943       0.15
36  36 9.817       0.16
37  37 10.78       0.18
38  38 11.83       0.19
39  39 12.99       0.21
40  40 14.26       0.23
41  41 15.65       0.24
42  42 17.18       0.25
43  43 18.86       0.27
44  44 20.70       0.28
45  45 22.73       0.30
46  46 24.95       0.30
47  47 27.39       0.29
48  48 30.07       0.27
49  49 33.01       0.23
50  50 36.24       0.21
51  51 39.78       0.20
52  52 43.67       0.21
53  53 47.94       0.22
54  54 52.62       0.19
55  55 57.77       0.13
56  56 63.41      0.070
57  57 69.61      0.055
58  58 76.42      0.087
59  59 83.89       0.14
60  60 92.09       0.17
61  61 101.1       0.17
62  62 111.0       0.18
63  63 121.8       0.27
64  64 133.7       0.43
65  65 146.8       0.64
66  66 161.2       0.88
67  67 176.9       1.16
68  68 194.2       1.51
69  69 213.2       1.94
70  70 234.1       2.47
71  71 256.9       3.16
72  72 282.1       4.03
73  73 309.6       5.02
74  74 339.9       6.05
75  75 373.1       6.96
76  76 409.6       7.63
77  77 449.7       8.01
78  78 493.6       8.08
79  79 541.9       7.82
80  80 594.9       7.13
81  81 653.0       6.01
82  82 716.8       4.81
83  83 786.9       3.57
84  84 863.9       2.09
85  85 948.3       1.01
86  86  1041       0.55
87  87  1143       0.22
88  88  1255      0.018
89  89  1377          0
90  90  1512          0
91  91  1660          0
92  92  1822          0
93      2000
```

Here is a output of `dput`

```
dput(data2)
structure(list(run = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
"75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", 
"86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", ""), size = c("0.375", 
"0.412", "0.452", "0.496", "0.545", "0.598", "0.656", "0.721", 
"0.791", "0.868", "0.953", "1.047", "1.149", "1.261", "1.385", 
"1.520", "1.668", "1.832", "2.011", "2.207", "2.423", "2.660", 
"2.920", "3.205", "3.519", "3.863", "4.240", "4.655", "5.110", 
"5.610", "6.158", "6.760", "7.421", "8.147", "8.943", "9.817", 
"10.78", "11.83", "12.99", "14.26", "15.65", "17.18", "18.86", 
"20.70", "22.73", "24.95", "27.39", "30.07", "33.01", "36.24", 
"39.78", "43.67", "47.94", "52.62", "57.77", "63.41", "69.61", 
"76.42", "83.89", "92.09", "101.1", "111.0", "121.8", "133.7", 
"146.8", "161.2", "176.9", "194.2", "213.2", "234.1", "256.9", 
"282.1", "309.6", "339.9", "373.1", "409.6", "449.7", "493.6", 
"541.9", "594.9", "653.0", "716.8", "786.9", "863.9", "948.3", 
"1041", "1143", "1255", "1377", "1512", "1660", "1822", "2000"
), percentage = c("0.013", "0.023", "0.034", "0.049", "0.061", 
"0.072", "0.083", "0.093", "0.10", "0.11", "0.12", "0.12", "0.13", 
"0.14", "0.14", "0.15", "0.15", "0.16", "0.17", "0.17", "0.18", 
"0.19", "0.20", "0.21", "0.22", "0.24", "0.25", "0.26", "0.28", 
"0.30", "0.31", "0.33", "0.35", "0.37", "0.39", "0.42", "0.45", 
"0.47", "0.50", "0.53", "0.56", "0.58", "0.59", "0.59", "0.58", 
"0.55", "0.52", "0.49", "0.46", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.44", 
"0.42", "0.38", "0.35", "0.32", "0.31", "0.33", "0.36", "0.42", 
"0.49", "0.59", "0.74", "0.94", "1.19", "1.49", "1.82", "2.18", 
"2.55", "2.94", "3.34", "3.78", "4.25", "4.73", "5.20", "5.60", 
"5.87", "5.93", "5.77", "5.37", "4.77", "4.03", "3.21", "2.36", 
"1.55", "0.81", "0.30", "0.056", "0.0044", "0", "0", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-93L))
```

I have tried the following code, which I would think should give me the results that I'd like:

```
clay <- data2 %>% filter(size <= 2)
silt <- data2 %>% filter(size > 2 & size <= 50)
sand <- data2 %>% filter(size > 50 & size <= 2000)
sum(as.numeric(clay$percentage), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 8.637
sum(as.numeric(silt$percentage), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 57.217
sum(as.numeric(sand$percentage), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 0
```

However, as you can see, the totals do not add up to what they should when looking at the dataset.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have you chcked the `class` of the columns.  is it `factor`?  in that case, you need `as.numeric(as.character`

Comment: I get `sum(as.numeric(sand$percentage), na.rm=TRUE)#
[1] 92.66#` `sum(as.numeric(silt$percentage), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 6.327` and `sum(as.numeric(clay$percentage), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1.039`

Comment: @joran just added that output for you. I'm not very familiar with the program that gave me this data, but I believe that they are NAs, which is why I used `na.rm=TRUE`

Comment: @akrun did you do anything different to get that? That is what they should look like, but I'm not getting those outputs when I run this code. Also, when I check class, they are characters

Comment: @Trev. i had the columns read as `numeric`.  If you have `factor` columns, convret to numeric by `as.numeric(as.character` instead of `as.numeric` direectly on it

Comment: Also, since thee `size` is character` you may need `as.numeric(size) > 2`

Comment: When I change the `as.numeric` sections to `as.numeric(as.character)`, nothing different happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Trev `as.numeric(as.character(data2$size))` is what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can try to convert the factor variable into numeric:

```r
data2$size <- as.numeric(levels(data2$size))[data2$size]
```

and then create a column with each group, which i think it's better than creating three separate data-frames.

```r
library(dplyr)

data2 <- data2 %>% 
  mutate(
    group = case_when(
      size < 2 ~ 'Group 1',
      size >= 2 & size < 50 ~'Group 2',
      size >= 50 ~ 'Group 3',
    ))
```

It yields the same result as in @akrun:

```
sum(data2$percentage[data2$group=='Group 1'])
#[1] 1.75
sum(data2$percentage[data2$group=='Group 2'])
#[1] 13.5
sum(data2$percentage[data2$group=='Group 3'])
#[1] 84.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! When i do the code that you shared, my size factor becomes a string of NAs. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It's working fine here. However, you should look it up this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information) to find more information about this procedure. It's best to treat numeric or integer variables as they are. Factor variables, as far as i can tell, are best suited for categorical variables.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use that to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the type of the columns.  The columns types can be automatically changed with `type.convert` from `base R` or `type_convert` from `readr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr) 
data2 <- data2 %>%
            type_convert
```

Note that the comparisons with `character` class is not doing what we expect to

```
'13.5' > 2
#[1] FALSE
```

as according to `?Comparison`

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

---

After changing the type, running the OP's code gives

```
sum(clay$percentage, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 1.748
sum(silt$percentage, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 13.5
sum(sand$percentage, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 84.7504
```